# How to deploy simple multi-container app for Azure Container Registry containing Volumes?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-volume

I want to deploy a simple multi-container app to Azure Container Registry. The issues that I am facing are,

- ACR wants me to mount volumes from Azure Storage Account >> File Share
- To use that for mounting volume, my `docker-compose.yml` (see below) needs to mention `azure_file` as driver as mentioned by Docker [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers).
- I am not sure how to install `azure_file` driver on Windows, and also the repo itself has been archived since 2018 and does not recommend using it. They are guiding to use `docker/cloudstor` of which I am unable to find tutorials or installation.
- I am unable to build the image locally and push to ACR, because of lack of installation of `azure_file` driver.

What are my options in this case? I am following the official Azure [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) to push my image onto ACR.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: flask-app
    container_name: flask-app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - code:/code
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis

volumes:
  code:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myacishare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host="redis", port=6379)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    redis.incr("hits")
    return "This Compose/Flask demo has been viewed %s time(s)." % redis.get("hits")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
flask
redis
```

Comment: You should delete that specific `volumes:` from your `docker-compose.yml`.  Your code is self-contained in the image; it doesn't need to be in a volume.

Comment: Hey David, I am using `volumes` here as an example. My final template resembles the following example, which justifies having `volumes`

https://github.com/testdrivenio/flask-on-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install the driver for the Azure file share. You just need to set the azure_file as you showed when you follow the steps to install the Docker Desktop for Windows. It will create the storage file share for you in the resource group.

And if you use the ACR to store your custom image, then you need to log in the ACR like this:

```
docker login myacr.azurecr.io -u xxxx -p xxxxx
```

You'd better use the same Azure account that you log in for the ACR context. Note that you need to assign the account enough permission of the ACR. For example, `AcrPull` role.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Charles. From what I know, after I log into ACR, I have to push the image to ACR. To push to ACR, I need to build the image locally first and then push. When I run `docker-compose up --build` using default docker context, I am still facing the same error `ERROR: Volume code specifies nonexistent driver azure_file`. I am sure the image will work on Azure using the `acicontext`, but how should I push it to ACR first without building locally? I am following the linked tutorial from Azure, which is working sans volumes.

Comment: @Shantanu To build the image in the ACR without push action, you can use the Azure CLI command `az acr build`, and according to my knowledge, when you set the volume with the driver `azure_file`, then it will create the storage account and the file share for you itself, you don't need to do anything else. It works like it on my side.

Comment: @Shantanu Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hey Charles, the `az acr build` command helped me out. The flask app is running now. Although, for this example, I am facing an issue where the redis service is not being accessed. I am not sure if this is a vnet issue or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, the issue I found with `az acr build` is that it is looking for a Dockerfile primarily. When I run the command `az acr build --registry registryname --image app_flask --file ./docker-compose.yml .` I am getting the error `unexpected dockerfile format`.

I am unable to find tutorials which show how to use a `docker-compose.yml` for container groups. The official Azure documentaiton for `az acr build` also insists that `--file` flag will look for a Dockerfile.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Shantanu The command `az acr build` just help you create one image, so you only can use the Dockerfile, not the docker-compose.yaml. If you use the docker-compose.yaml, you only can use the `docker compose` command and it seems that it only help you create the images locally.

Comment: This seems like a major gap. Do you know if there is a way around it, or AKS is the only option here?

Comment: @Shantanu The ACI is the choice for quick running and test. But if you need to use it for a long time service, AKS is a better choice. perhaps the App Service is also a choice, but it has less control than AKS. So here the AKS is the only option.

Comment: @Shantanu Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Hey Charles, I am closing this question, but for whoever is viewing this, `docker-compose.yml` is not entirely supported on Azure Containers Instances. The best option to look out for will be Azure Kubernetes Service.